# Transfer files to dropbox from node js without browser based oauth authentication

Tags: node.js, express, dropbox-api

I am running a nodejs + express based api server from heroku and using the [dropbox-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js) library.  Here's what I'd like to do:

1. A user hits a specific api endpoint and kicks off the process.
2. Generate some text files via a node process and save them on the server
3. Transfer these files to a dropbox that I own using my own credentials (user and dropbox app).

There will never be a case when a random user needs to do this.. it's a team account and this is an internal tool.

The part that is tripping me up is that dropbox wants to open a browser window and get permission from me to connect to the app.  The issue is that I obviously can't click the button when the process is running on the heroku instance.

Is there any way for me to authorize access to the app totally in node?

I feel like I could potentially use a phantomJS process to click the button - but it seems too complicated and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Here is my authentication code:

```
    // Libraries
    var Dropbox         = require('dropbox');

    var DROPBOX_APP_KEY    = "key";
    var DROPBOX_APP_SECRET = "secret";

    var dbClient = new Dropbox.Client({
      key: DROPBOX_APP_KEY, secret: DROPBOX_APP_SECRET, sandbox: false
    });

    dbClient.authDriver(new Dropbox.Drivers.NodeServer(8191));

    dbClient.authenticate(function(error, client) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Some shit happened trying to authenticate with dropbox");
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }


      client.writeFile("test.txt", "sometext", function (error, stat) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }

        console.log("file saved!");
        console.log(stat);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Took me a bit of testing, but it's possible.

First, you need to authenticate through the browser and save the token and token secret that are returned by Dropbox:

```
dbClient.authenticate(function(error, client) {
  console.log('connected...');
  console.log('token ', client.oauth.token);       // THE_TOKEN
  console.log('secret', client.oauth.tokenSecret); // THE_TOKEN_SECRET
  ...
});
```

Once you have the token and the secret, you can use them in the `Dropbox.Client` constructor:

```
var dbClient = new Dropbox.Client({
  key         : DROPBOX_APP_KEY,
  secret      : DROPBOX_APP_SECRET,
  sandbox     : false,
  token       : THE_TOKEN,
  tokenSecret : THE_TOKEN_SECRET
});
```

After that, you won't get bothered with having to authenticate through a browser anymore (or at least not until someone runs the code again without the token and the secret, which will make Dropbox generate a new token/secret pair and invalidate the old ones, or the apps credentials are revoked).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to test that out!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm using the above code with a key, secret, token key and token secret that I know to all be valid, and I'm unable to get anything beyond an unauthorized error when I try to upload a file. What am I missing here?

Comment: Update: My guess is this is related to dropbox-js moving to oauth2, but it seems like the credentials are changing; I'm caching a single token rather than a token and secret, and that's doing the trick.

Comment: I found this site that makes it easy to generate an oauth2 token for use in this manner: https://dbxoauth2.site44.com

Answer (score 9):

Or you can just use the Implicit grant and get the oauth token.

```
        var client = new Dropbox.Client({
            key: "xxxxx",
            secret: "xxxxx",
            token:"asssdsadadsadasdasdasdasdaddadadadsdsa", //got from implicit grant
            sandbox:false
        });
```

No need to get to the browser at all.This line is no longer required!

```
   client.authDriver(new Dropbox.AuthDriver.NodeServer(8191));
```

Comment: This is correct, but it's called an access token, not implicit grant: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/05/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account/

Comment: Yes, this is the best way to procedure.